# shell script not working properly

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, scripts

I'm writing the below script but it seems not to work as this is the output:

```
## entered first loop ##
[==1.0]: command not found
[==2.0]: command not found
## entered first loop ##
[==1.0]: command not found
[==2.0]: command not found
## entered first loop ##
[==1.0]: command not found
[==2.0]: command not found
## entered first loop ##
[==1.0]: command not found
[==2.0]: command not found
```

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a arr1=("1000/1.0" "2000/2.0" "3000/3.0" "4000/4.0") &&
declare -a arr2=("100/0.138" "200/0.098" "300/0.07347" "400/0.0545" "500/0.0449") &&

for i in "${arr1[@]}" &&
do &&
    echo -e "\e[41m## entered first loop ##\e[0m" 
    str1=$i | cut -d'/' -f1 &&
    str2=$i | cut -d'/' -f2 &&
    if [str2="1.0"] &&
    then &&
        sed -i 's/1.0/1.0/g' file1.txt &&
    else  &&
        sed -i 's/$ii/$str2/g' file1.txt &&
    fi &&

    for j in "${arr2[@]}" &&
    do &&
        echo -e "\e[41m## entered second loop ##\e[0m" 
        str3=$j | cut -d'/' -f1 &&
        str4=$j | cut -d'/' -f2 &&
        old_loc="test_name=name_([^]+)_ni_([^]+)" &&
        new_loc="test_name=name_$str1_ni_str3" &&
        sed -i 's/old_loc/new_loc/g' file2.sh &&

        old_loc2="#hello HELLO ([^]+) // 4 am" &&
        new_loc2="#hello HELLO $str4 // 4 am" &&
        sed -i 's/old_loc2/new_loc2/g' file.cpp &&

    done 
    ii=$str2 &&
    if [str2="2.0"] &&
        break
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed a few syntactical errors in your file, and removed all the `&&`s.
The main problem was your array declaration and the IF statements. Here is the result:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a arr1=("1000/1.0", "2000/2.0", "3000/3.0", "4000/4.0")
declare -a arr2=("100/0.138", "200/0.098", "300/0.07347", "400/0.0545", "500/0.0449")

for i in "${arr1[@]}"
do
    echo -e "\e[41m## entered first loop ##\e[0m" 
    str1=$i | cut -d'/' -f1
    str2=$i | cut -d'/' -f2
    if [ "$str2" = "1.0" ]
    then
        sed -i 's/1.0/1.0/g' file1.txt
    else
        sed -i 's/$ii/$str2/g' file1.txt
    fi

    for j in "${arr2[@]}"
    do
        echo -e "\e[41m## entered second loop ##\e[0m" 
        str3=$j | cut -d'/' -f1
        str4=$j | cut -d'/' -f2
        old_loc="test_name=name_([^]+)_ni_([^]+)"
        new_loc="test_name=name_$str1_ni_str3"
        sed -i 's/old_loc/new_loc/g' file2.sh

        old_loc2="#hello HELLO ([^]+) // 4 am"
        new_loc2="#hello HELLO $str4 // 4 am"
        sed -i 's/old_loc2/new_loc2/g' file.cpp

    done
    ii=$str2
    if [ "$str2" = "2.0" ]
    then
        break
    fi
done
```